# 'argv' is not defined when running mutool run script.js

Tags: javascript, mupdf

I am trying to pass a file name into my JavaScript script, similarly to the example code here: https://mupdf.com/docs/examples/draw-document.js

```
C:\Tools\mupdf-1.14.0-windows> .\mutool.exe run .\script.js c:\temp\test.pdf
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: `'argv'` is not defined

The documentation (https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-run.html) says:

> [...] the command line arguments are accessible from the global 'argv' object.

The underlying code looks like this (this is just *'proof of concept'* code):

```
var doc = new Document(argv[1]);
var outline = doc.loadOutline();
var outlineString = JSON.stringify(outline, {}, 2);

var txt = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = txt.CreateTextFile("c:\\temp\\text.json", true);
s.Write(outlineString);
s.Close();
```

Could someone point out the error I'm making please?

Just to point out that in a perfect world, I'd like to convert the JSON object to an XML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MuTool 1.14.0-rc1 [Changelog](https://mupdf.com/release_history.html):

> - mutool run: Pass arguments to script in scriptArgs global.

So, you should use `scriptArgs` rather than `argv` in your script.

Cheers,
Rom